# Format an SD Card used as Android adopted storage (android_meta and android_extended)

Tags: partitioning, android, sd-card, partition-recovery

I have this SanDisk 32GB MicroSD card that's ended with two partitions `android_meta` and `android_extended` as result of a failed attempt to use the card as Adopted Storage in a Lenovo Phone.

Neither Windows or Android now detect the card, and I've tried quite a few methods to get the card to work. These include using diskpart, chkdsk, testdisk.exe, mounting it using a pc running linux and using a few other disk repair softwares. But, none seem to be able to format the disk.

Is there a way I can get this card back to normal. It's a blank card so data recovery does not matter.